# How to show/hide div in WinJS Template dynamically

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have a Windows 8 app with a template that contains a div I want to show or hide based on the value of a property inside a `data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template"`. I have tried the following without luck:

```
<div data-win-bind="visible: isMore"> ..content... </div>
```

where `isMore` is a boolean property of the databound item.

How can I do that? I guess the visible property does not exist?

Answer (score 14):

You are right - the `visible` property doesn't exist, but you can control the appearance using CSS and a binding converter.

First, use `WinJS.Binding.converter` to create a converter function that translates a boolean to a value value for the CSS display property, like this:

```
var myConverter = WinJS.Binding.converter(function (val) {
    return val ? "block" : "none";
});
```

Make sure that the function is globally available - I use `WinJS.Namespace.define` to create collections of these converters that I can get to globally.

Now you can use the converter in your data binding to control the CSS display property, like this:

```
<div data-win-bind="style.display: isMore myConverter"> ..content... </div>
```

Comment: even better would be to set the display style to "initial" instead of "block" so it can be used for `span` elements too.

Comment: I use display:none property.. data removed from the element but element with blank display exist there... It takes size of first row by default.